# Problem from Cutland's Computability: 3.2. problem 3

Tags: logic, proof-verification, computability

The problem goes as follows. Let  f: N --> N, such that f is partial, N is the natural numbers, and let m $\in$ N. Construct a non-computable function g such that 
g(x) = f(x) for x$\le$m.

Proof: By Cantor's theorem, there exist uncountably many functions on the naturals, including partial, non-computable ones. Call this class of all partial functions Z. Suppose we are given an f from Z. Either f will be computable or it will not be. We must show that there is an x, and a g, such that f(x) = g(x) with x$\le$m: m$\in$N and g non-computable.

Two cases eventuate:

1. f is *non*-computable. Then we can set g = f.
2. f *is* computable.

Need help with (what looks like) non-trivial case. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If $h(x)$ is a noncomputable total function, $f(x)$ is any function, and $m$ is fixed,
then 
$$
h'(x) = \begin{cases}
h(x) : x > m \\
f(x) : x \leq m,f(x) \downarrow\\
0 : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is a total, noncomputable function that agrees with $f$ (when $f$ is defined) for all $x \leq m$.

Comment: Carl -- Thanks so much, just to make sure I follow you: Given an f which is any function (computable or not) and a fixed m $\in$ N, you can always define another function h which agrees with it, having the desired property when f is defined. Correct?:

Comment: Yes. If $h$ is already noncomputable and you change only a finite number of values, the new function will still be noncomputable. So you can just change the values less than $m$ to match $f$.

Comment: Thanks Carl & Mauro, you two are awesome. I hope the gods of mathstackexchange see fit to reward your clarity via more badges and such. You might be seeing a lot more of my fumbling around with computability, and I hope to see more of your suggestions as I tread ever so lightly through a field I do not understand at all. (I'd like to see up to Sacks' density theorem!)

Answer (score 0):

The original question actually has more subtlety: Cutland asks us to construct $g$ s. t. $g(x) \simeq f(x)$ for $x \le m$, according to definitions given in the prologue, that means that for any $x \le m$, the expressions $g (x)$ and $f(x)$ are either both defined, or both undefined, and if defined they are equal.

Hence the approach may be not that straightforward, for we need the two functions to coincide for all $x \leq m$, and for $x > m$, apply diagonal method, but instead of making $g(x)$ different from $\phi_x(x)$ (where $\phi_x$ means the function computed by the program with code number $x$), some shifting of the latter is needed, which is not difficult to figure out.